# Don't show site collection from global search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I have 3 site collections in my tenant:

- https://top-level (site T)
- https://top-level/restricted (site R)
- https://top-level/accessible (site A)

How do I make sure that in the global search for Site T that it will not show results from Site R?

I still want search to work within Site R though and there is restriction in permissions in place: Everyone can still see all items within the 3 sites.